# How can I manually customize the size of the Avatar in the library react-rainbow-component?

Tags: react-rainbow-components

How can I manually customize the size of the Avatar in the library react-rainbow-component? I used the size prop and set it to large but it was too small for me so I want to make it a custom size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom size using the `className` or `style` props, for example using `style`

```
<Avatar
    style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
    src="images/user/user1.jpg"
    title=“John Doe" />
```

You can see an example here
https://react-rainbow.io/#!/Avatar/9